# Cannot log in after installing OpenBSD cwm window manager on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, login, window-manager

I installed the OpenBSD cwm window manager and now it is not letting me log in.

What can I do?

Comment: A _window manager_ does not handle graphical login; that's the task of a _display manager_ like _lightdm_, _GDM_, _sddm_. If you don't see a graphical login, what else did you change?

Comment: Is there really no graphical login? If there is, check if there isn't any icon to change the _session type_. You will probably still have other session types to choose from; installing an additional window manager does not remove an existing graphical desktop (GNOME or KDE Plasma or Xfce or whatever else you had installed).

Comment: See also https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/change-default-display-manager-ubuntu-20-04/

Comment: I wonder if this is really about a CSM _window manager_ (I found nothing about that one), or if it's really about the [_Compatibility Support Module_ (CSM)](https://superuser.com/questions/857117/what-is-csm-option) as an alternative to UEFI.

Comment: HuHa this is the video of what is going on https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Vy3DSxcRAw3hWtVcdfJ_sqFdzbmqdZL/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Cannot really watch video. What model Dell? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Comment: So it was _CWM_, not _CSM_; okay, that's something completely different. Since you wrote that changing from _GDM_ to _lightdm_ fixed it, you most likely previously had _Wayland_, not _X11_ (a.k.a. _Xorg_), but CWM needs X11. By changing the display manager to lightdm you implicitly also changed from Wayland to X11.

Comment: @oldfred The video shows that the laptop boots to the UEFI setup utility and after selecting from the boot menu it gets stuck at a black screen showing a large Dell logo.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the default desktop manager from GDM to LightDM.